# Cases Permissions in Customer Community

Tags: community, customer-community

We've granted our customers access to submit cases within our Community. In order for them to be able to add attachments, they needed Edit permissions on the Case. In turn, the buttons "Edit" and "Change Record Type" are now visible when the customer is viewing the case.

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone know how we can remove the buttons? Salesforce Support said we cannot remove those unless we remove the Edit permissions. I'm hoping for a different solution so it's not one way or the other.

Comment: did you give the below answer a try?

Answer (score 0):

A `Non-Secure` workaround (`Emphasis on not recommended`) would be to use CSS and not display them. This is subject to break, if there are css scoping changes when updating your template.

for this example, i just checked the selector path for the button group, you can change the scope based on your needs:

```
#NapiliCommunityTemplate > div.cCenterPanel > div > div.row.contentPanel >
div > div > div:nth-child(1) > header > div.slds-page-header.s1FixedFullWidth.
forceHighlightsStencilDesktop > div >div.slds-col.slds-no-flex.slds-grid.
slds-align-middle.actionsContainer > ul {
    display: none;
}
```

you can apply the css via community branding.

If you need to customize what buttons and actions your users can do, a custom component could be more appropriate for your use case.